# Prove that, for every natural number, their factorization as primes is unique

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, prime-factorization, natural-numbers

I need some feedback on this proof I wrote that:

$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N} \text{ assumed the existence of a factorization of } n \text{ as } n = p_1p_2\cdots p_k, \text{ where } p_i, (1 \leq i \leq k) \text{ is a prime number, such factorization is unique.}$$

My proof:

Due to the well-ordering theorem, if there exists a set of natural numbers that can be factorized in two different ways, there exists a least element of such set.

Let $n$ be the least number that has two different prime factorizations.
Then
$$n = p_1p_1\cdots p_k$$
and also
$$n = q_1q_2\cdots q_s$$
Assuming all common factors have been crossed out, $\forall 1 \leq i, j \leq s,k, p_i \neq q_j$.

Without loss of generality, assume $q_1 > p_1$.
Now let $m:= (q_1-p_1)q_2\cdots q_k$ .
Then $$m = q_1q_2\cdots q_k - p_1q_2\cdots q_k = n - p_1q_2\cdots q_k \tag{ $\dagger$ }$$ Then $m<n$.

Plugging the two factorizations of $n$ into our expression $(\dagger)$, we get:

(1) $m = p_1p_2\cdots p_s-p_1 q_2\cdots q_k$

(2) $m =q_1q_2\cdots q_k - p_1q_2\cdots q_k$

Note that the factor $q_1$ is present in expression (2), but not in (1). Therefore, those two expressions are different prime factorizations of $m$. However, we have that $m<n$ and what we found contradicts the assumption that $n$ was the least element to have such a property.

Therefore, no natural number has such a property.                                                                                                                                                                             □

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd consider a simpler proof by noting that if a prime $p$ divides a product $ab$, then $p$ divides a factor, i.e. $a$ or $b$.

Then in your ansatz, $p_1\cdots p_k = n =q_1\ldots q_l$, the prime $p_1$ divides the rhs and must be equal to a prime $q_j$. W.l.o.g. take $j=1$.

Then one can apply the shortening rule such that $p_2\cdots p_k=q_2\ldots q_l < n$. Now apply induction.